# How to cache loop in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I have got external loop with loop inside:

```
<tr *ngFor="let pupil of pupils">

<md-select [(ngModel)]="selectedClassNumber">
<md-option *ngFor="let cls of classesNumbers" [value]="cls.classNumber">{{ cls.classNumber }}
</md-option>
</md-select>

</tr>
```

As you can see there is an loop i for `md-select`. It work so slowly when notes are over 50.

Comment: and the question is...? what do you mean with `cache the loop`? you have a list of pupils and classesNumbers yet

Comment: question is that I iterate the same md-select in each of row. The same data in md-select

Comment: so you don't want to iterate md-select inside pupils loop? just put it outside <tr>... as written like this i see: 1 pupil --> all classesNumbers; 2 pupil --> all classesNumbers... etc etc